# Link fragment to item in drawerlayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can any one tell me what is wrong here? .I am basically just trying to tell it if position is 0 then set the fragment to R.layout.fragment_fragmenta .

As an error i get a NullPointerException. Any help would be appreciated guys. 
Thanks in advance,

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity  implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private android.view.ViewGroup container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((Color.parseColor("#CC3232"))));
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    drawerListener= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_action_expand,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Drawer Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Drawer Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerListener.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    selectItem(position);
    if(position==0){

        setTitle("Fragment1");

        Fragment fragment = new fragmenta();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

    }
}

public void selectItem(int position){
   listView.setItemChecked(position,true);

}
public void setTitle(String title){
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

}

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
String[] items;
int[] images ={R.drawable.abc_ic_go, R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad,R.drawable.camera,R.drawable.abc_ic_search, R.drawable.phone,R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search};
public MyAdapter(Context context)
   {
    this.context=context;
   items=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    }
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = null;
    if(convertView==null){
      LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
   }
    else {
        row=convertView;
   }
   TextView titleTextView =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   titleTextView.setText(items[position]);
   titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    return row;
}
```

}

This is the Fragment class :

```
public class fragmenta extends Fragment {


public fragmenta() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmenta, container, false);
}
```

}

And this is the error log  :

```
08-28 14:42:07.817  22629-22629/com.example.dell.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1:    thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41944da0)
08-28 14:42:07.817  22629-22629/com.example.dell.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL      EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dell.myapplication, PID: 22629
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:395)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:430)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:422)
        at com.example.dell.myapplication.MyActivity.onItemClick(MyActivity.java:119)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1524)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3531)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4898)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is on MyActivity.java:119 ?

Comment: I updated the entire file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

**CHECK THIS**

```
Fragment fragment = new YOURFRAGMENTNAME();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: @zakbennani Please check the layout file can u plz upload the Log